# window.postMessage from web_accessible_resource to content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, postmessage

i try to post a message from a web_accessible_resource to a content-script of my chrome extension.

### My Setup:

**parts of my manifest.json:**

```
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["http://*/*"],
  "js": ["content.js"]
}],
"web_accessible_resources": ["run.js"]
```

**content.js**

```
// this listener is never triggered ;-(
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) { 
  if (request.type === 'foo') {
    // do whatever i want if request.type is foo       
  }
});
```

**run.js**

```
window.postMessage({type: 'foo'}, '*');
```

### Things i also tried that worked:

#### Adding a listener directly in run.js:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(msg) {
  if (msg.data.type === 'foo') {
    // that one works
  }
});
```

#### Posting a Message from a background script:

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function (tab) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {type: "foo"});
});
```

### Question:

What do i have to do? do i need to set some authorisation or something for my content-script or why does this not work???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now enable the api to send messages directly from a webpage to your extension id

Enable in manifest

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["*://*.example.com/*"]
}
```

Send message from webpage:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(editorExtensionId, {openUrlInEditor: url},
  function(response) {
    if (!response.success)
      handleError(url);
  });
```

Receive in extension:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(function(){});
```

See: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage

Comment: This is not supported in Firefox.
In chrome, until recently, you couldn't specify `"matches": "<all_urls>"` for `externally_connectable`.

Answer (score 2):

just when i asked my question, i had an idea which of course...

... WORKED.

of course i need to attach a window.addEventListener in my content.js:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
  if (e.data.type === 'closeSidebar') {
    // that works now
  }
});
```

Comment: this question and answer is almost 3 years old. things have probably changed, but thanks for the downvote...

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer.
This is the way to go if you want to communicate from web page <-> content script, for all domains.
This is the only way supported in Firefox.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/externally_connectable