# Post message from web_accessible_resource to ContentScript

Tags: google-chrome-extension, postmessage

Am trying to post message from my `Web Accessible Resource` file (actually a HTML file, which has a JS attached to it) to `ContentScript`; but event listeners are not working properly..!

app.js:

```
window.postMessage({myName: 'Sagar'}, '*');
```

contentscript.js

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(request) { 
//My Code 
}, true);
```

manifest.json

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["jquery-1.11.3.min.js", "content-script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["Tracker.html"]
```

Tracker.html has `app.js` referenced in it..

Where Am I going wrong?

There's a post over [window.postMessage from web_accessible_resource to content script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18055800/window-postmessage-from-web-accessible-resource-to-content-script), which doesn't seem to be working..!!!

Comment: Could you please provide more code? Like the whole manifest file and where do you use Tracker.html?